# String manipulation - Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I have a file called notification.txt that has data in it that I need to trim and pass the trimmed output to another command.

File is a random number of lines, could be 1, could be 100+, they look like this:

```
hostname.domain.xyz                      Notification
hostname.domain.xyz                      Notification
hostname.domain.xyz                      Notification
hostname.domain.xyz                      Notification
```

I'm looking to trim everything from the first `.` to the right and it will just leave me with the hostname in a array/variable that I can then use to pass to another command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove everything after the first occurrence of `.` by calling `Split` and discarding everything except for the first part:

```
$strings = @(
  'host1.domain.tld       Notification'
  'host2.domain.tld       Notification'
  'host3.domain.tld       Notification'
  'host4.domain.tld       Notification'
  'host5.domain.tld       Notification'
)

$hostnames = $strings |ForEach-Object { $_.Split('.')[0] }
```

`$_.Split('.')` returns a string array (eg. `@('host1','domain','tld  Notification')`), and `[0]` gives us the first element in said array

---

Alternatively, use the `-replace` regex operator:

```
$hostnames = $strings -replace '\..*$'
```

The regex pattern `\..*$` will match the first literal dot `.` and everything after it until the end of the string, and since we're using the `-replace` operator with no substitute string as the second argument, that entire part gets removed.